# Using Bayes rule

Tags: probability

There are two schools in a village: School A and School B

- School A has twice as many pupils as School B
- At School A, 70% of the pupils are girls
- At School B, 40% of the pupils are girls

i) You meet a pupil from the village. What is the probability that this pupil is a boy?

ii) Charlie is a boy who goes to either School A or School B. What is the probability that Charlie goes to School A?

My attempts:

i) 
Since school A has twice has many pupils, I give it double weighting.

School A: (1 - 0.7)*2 = 0.6

School B: 1 - 0.4 = 0.6

Probability = average of A and B = 0.6

---

ii)
P(School A|Boy) = (P(Boy|School A) * P(School A)) / P(Boy)

P(Boy|School A) = 0.3 because probability of boy, given school A

P(School A) = 2/3 because twice as many pupils in school A

P(Boy) from part i

P(School A|Boy) = (0.3 * 2/3) / 0.6

P(School A|Boy) = 1/3

---

Have I got these right?

Thanks

Comment: It's sometimes helpful to think through numerical examples.  Say $A$ has $30$ boys and $70$ girls, and $B$ has $30$ boys and $20$ girls. That fits your requirements, yes?   Then there are $60$ boys all in all out of $150$ students.  Does that fit your answer for (i)?  Note too that each school has the same number of boys.  Does that fit your answer for (ii)?

Comment: Note:  your notation is very confusing.  I think (but am not sure) that you are using "$A$" to denote the event "a randomly observed child attends school $A$" but you are using "$B$" to denote the event "a randomly observed child is a boy".  At the very least, you should define the variables you want to use.

Comment: In $(a)$, you need to multiply $1-0.7$ by $2/3$, not $2$.  Similarly, $1-0.4$ gets multiplied by $1/3$. The 'weighting' you are talking about is a probability.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Updated notation, hopefully less confusing now. So is the probability of being a boy 60/150 = 0.4? If so, would I be correct in saying the answer for part 2 is 0.5?